# Barn reinforcement

Tags: structural, barn

I have an old barn that was resting on a stone foundation that was in rough shape. The foundation was only about 3-4 feet tall but it was starting to deteriorate. The barn is 24x26 and has two stories.

We lifted the barn -> leveled it out and poured a new slab that it sits on and is fastened to. We removed the old floor that sat about 8 feet high and built a new floor that sits about 12 feet high.

Two trusses were built to support new floor.

Upstairs there were 2x6's running from peak down diagonally down to double plate. These have been converted into roof trusses as shown in pictures along with some continual lateral bracing that ties them all together.

What can I do to try and firm things up?

During the occasional 100km/h gusts we get, the barns moves quite a bit and pops like hell.

Here is a diagram of the barn. The new floor (3/4 inch tongue and groove plywood) sits on top of those two red trusses.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Most of the stuff that you described are parts of the building's gravity system. The lateral system resists wind. That's the sheathing on the outside of the walls, the yellow diagonal braces, the roof sheathing, and the elevated floor's sheathing. Does the entire structure flex excessively (suggesting a problem down low like the wall sheathing)? Or does the entire structure only flex excessively above a particular elevation?

Comment: Are those 2x4 walls? You said that you increased their span from 8 ft to 12 ft? Is it that wall, maybe, with flexing 2x4s that don't like the 12 ft distance to the floor elevation?

Comment: Hey Popham! Yes, they are true 2x4's and I think what may be happening is that the new floor height has created a sort of hinge. If you look at the wall on the right there is a sort of beam that runs across the wall that creates a "break." The 2x4's don't run all the way up like they do on the south and north walls. Both left and right walls have that beam configuration.

Comment: Here is a link to some framing pics: https://imgur.com/gallery/MPbsdjt

Comment: That interruption in the 2x4 studs would get modeled as a hinge in an analysis, but the hinge is stable. The 2x4s from above spans from roof to hinge without interruption, where they cantilever past the floor elevation, bracing the tops of the lower studs.

Comment: Fixing the sway problem requires what the IRC (a typical US code) calls "wall bracing." In the US, if you paid me to fix this, I would pretend that your exterior cladding provides no strength nor stiffening against sway and follow [IRC R602.12](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.12) to size OSB sheathing for the inside surface of the walls. Alternatively, people often install wire rope plus turnbuckle X-braces, or they threaded rod X-braces. Those are potentially cheaper options, but would require hand calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the help popham. I know the question is closed but you have been a huge help. You definitely pointed me in the right direction! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

*Braces not reconfigured in parallel with the change in floor elevation*:

The yellow braces are odd in that they don't end at the floor's elevation. If your old floor elevation needed and had braces ending at the floor elevation for strength purposes, then the new configuration has inadequate strength. Rather than analyzing whether the braces were necessary for strength, my instinct is to look at the old configuration. For all braces that ended at the old floor elevation, the braces should be modified to reach the new floor elevation.

Plywood wall panels on the inside surface of the walls can serve the same purpose as the braces, so if you intend to finish the interior of the walls somehow, then that finish may be an adequate substitute for any braces.

*Explanation*:

For lateral loading, there's basically constant stress in the walls between each floor elevation. As you scan down a structure, the stresses step up at each floor elevation as more wind load accumulates (it accumulates through wall studs, into floor diaphragms, and then into the walls at each floor elevation, hence the step pattern in the stresses). At the bottom of the structure there's the largest stress, the "base shear" stress. Your yellow braces don't reach the new floor elevation, so they relieve some of the board stress over the elevations that the brace spans. Above the top of the brace and below the elevated floor elevation, however, the boards get no relief in the current configuration.

The lack of relief is fine if the diagonal braces were intended merely to prevent swaying. If the boards alone were insufficient for all of the demand, however, and the braces were installed for strength purposes, then the new configuration has a strength problem. The prescription provided earlier would fix any strength problem after filtering out braces that obviously weren't installed for strength purposes (or maybe they were incompetently installed for strength purposes).

Comment: Is this intended to be a different/competing answer to the one you already wrote?

Comment: @brhans, this answers the generic theme of "barn reinforcement," but not any specifics from the question's body text. The flawed bracing most likely manifests as a lurking strength problem, not a flexibility problem as mentioned in the question's body text. If the comment character limit was larger, then this "answer" would be a comment. This indirectly answers his question, though, in that bracing is the solution to sway issues (once there's a proper load path from the floor diaphragm into the wall).

Answer (score 0):

*Bad load path from elevated floor diaphragm into brace wall line*:

Zooming in on the 2nd image, I see that there are no fasteners between the joist running parallel to the wall and the wall's framing. This is a mistake. For your balloon framing, that joist acts as a shear collector analogous to a top plate in a platform framed system. To transfer the diaphragm load of the floor sheathing into the wall, you need substantial fastenings between that joist and the wall's studs. Off the top of my head, I would use 3-16d common nails per stud analogous to nailing a bottom plate to joists (item 15 from the table below [IRC R602.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3)).

Assuming that the joist parallel with the wall at the other end is in a similar condition, obviously you should implement the same detail there as well.

While you're at it, you should also verify that the floor sheathing has been nailed to that joist every 6" with 8d common nails.

*How this stops the popping sounds*:

Currently the edge joist diaphragm loads go into the trusses at the truss ends, where those little areas at the ends of the trusses are good candidates for your popping noises. The edge joist to truss connection should be tremendously over-stressed. The truss is pushing sideways against the king studs for load transfer into the wall, where the wall sheathing fasteners are over-stressed in the neighborhood of the truss ends.

My other guess for the popping noise source is at the corners of the elevated floor. I imagine that there's also substantial diaphragm load transfer happening there at the wall-to-wall fastenings.

This is all predicated on the bad diaphragm connection theory. I'm predicting the popping sound locations based on that theory, so fixing the bad connection (the edge joist without fasteners to the the studs) would resolve the described popping causes.